# Storing Cell Array's in an Array

Tags: matlab

I am calling the function like so:

```
beta=NaN(size(rates,1),6);

mats=[1:50];

mats2=[2 5 10 30];

for i=1:2
y2=rates(i,mats2);
yM=rates(i,:);

dataList=struct('yM',yM,'mats',mats,'model',@NSS,'mats2',mats2,'y2',y2);

de=struct('min',[0;3.5],'max',[3.5;30],'d',2,'nP',200,'nG',600,'ww',0.1,'F',0.5,'CR',0.99,'R',0,'oneElementfromPm',1);


beta(i,:)=DElambdaVec(de,dataList,@OF);
end
```

However the output from DElabdavec, is a cell array:

```
output.Fbest=Fbest; output.xbest=xbest; output.Fbv=Fbv;
```

How can I store each of these items on each pass of the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the results to a cell array - beta in this case:

```
beta{i} = DElambdaVec(de,dataList,@OF);
```

Every element of `beta` is now an object returned by `DElambdaVec`, e.g.:

```
beta{1}

ans = 

Fbest: 'Fbest'
xbest: 'xbest'
  Fbv: 'Fbv'
```

I used example values to create the entries here.

Note that you have to initialize `beta=[]` before the loop.